# На какой CMS создаете сайты именно вы?

Tags: joomla, cms

Здравствуйте я только учусь созданию сайтов есть пара вопросов к бывалым:

Какие CMS используют веб студии и фрилансеры в создании сайтов интересует только **ЧТО ИСПОЛЬЗУЕТЕ ЛИЧНО ВЫ** и почему?

Еще вопрос пока что я знаком только с Joomla устаревают ли дополнительные компоненты у других CMS типа фотогалереи при обновлении версии CMS как у Joomla?

И последнее немного почитав у меня сложилось впечатление что разработчики сайтов недолюбливают Joomla но почему я так и не понял.

А еще кое что кто знаком с Joomla вот вышла новая версия 2.5 стоит ли ее использовать или пользоваться 1.6 или 1.7 в чем разница ? Не сырая ли 2.5 и чем она может быть хуже старых версий?

Заранее спасибо за ответы.

Comment: Эх... Никочу никого обидеть, по этому воздержусь от комментирования по поводу Joomla - овно редкосное!

Солидарен с ответившими по поводу своей собственной CMS, за что всем и плюсадин)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Пробовал 1С-битрикс не впечатлила

S.Builder - мне нравится эта платная CMS многофункциональная.

Своя CMS - тут без комментариев, т.к. у каждого она своя со своими плюсами и минусами.

ModX - нормальная системка.

Больше не хочу никакую расписывать.

Answer (score 2):

Свои системы пишу, получаю от этого удовольствие и опыт.

Answer (score 2):

Своя система, круче нету. Не используй не какие системы, пиши свою.

Если на хостинге где стоит joomla упадет php, я спокойно зайду в базу и сделаю с ней что захочу.

Answer (score 2):

Не фрилансер, но тоже отмечусь. Работаю с Abo.CMS: доков нормальных нет, сторонних модулей я не встречал. Но. Качественная техподдержка, работает партнерская программа (на ней можно заработать), разобравшись в логике CMS, легко клепать на ней что-то новое. Плюс, система дружелюбна к пользователям и их можно обучить пользоваться ею.

Answer (score 0):

Drupal - очень расширяем и гибок. Русское сообщество, хоть маленькое, но есть. Так что если трудности возникают, то есть у кого что спросить.
Но уровень знаний там нужен не малый и ещё умение в нём работать.
Не для начинающего.
Не шибко интуитивно-понятный интерфейс, но удобная\гибкая возможность реализовать ваши задумки.